# Error in remove Object +Relationship One to Many + Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, one-to-many

It is My Program

relationship between a Object and a SectionObject is One to Many and Relationship between two tables is based ObjectId.

first: set obj

```
private void ObjectAdd(...)
{
    obj = new Object(); //is Public
    obj = Shop.Objects.SingleOrDefault(S => S.IdObject == SelectedObjectId);
}
```

secound: add sectionObject in obj

```
private void BtnAddCategory(...)
{
    SectionObject SO = new SectionObject();
                SO.Section = Shop.Sections.SingleOrDefault(Sections => Sections.SectionId == FrmCategoryList.SelectedSectionId);

    obj.SectionObjects.Add(SO);
}
```

three: remove a SectionObject of obj

```
private void BtnDelCategory(...)
{
    SectionObject SO = new SectionObject();
              SO = obj.SectionObjects.SingleOrDefault(Sections => Sections.SectionId == Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value));

    obj.SectionObjects.Remove(SO);
}
```

final: insert obj in database

```
private void BtnAccept(...)
{
    Shop.Objects.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
    Shop.SubmitChanges(); // ERROR
}
```

ERROR is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  Message=An attempt was made to remove a relationship between a Object and a SectionObject. However, one of the relationship's foreign keys (SectionObject.ObjectId) cannot be set to null.
  Source=System.Data.Linq
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.SynchDependentData()
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.ValidateAll(IEnumerable`1 list)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.ObjectAdd.BtnAccept_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\EasySoft\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Shop 90.08.22\Shop10.4\Shop\ObjectAdd.cs:line 47
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the sectionobject for an object you need to set it's sectionobject.objectid property.
If you sunmit your changes straight after the add, youd get the same error. It's telling you have sectionobject with no foriegn key to object

Comment: i used this code, but not solved  


    SectionObject SO = new SectionObject();
    SO.ObjectId=obj.objectId;
    SO.Section = Shop.Sections.SingleOrDefault(Sections => Sections.SectionId == FrmCategoryList.SelectedSectionId);

    obj.SectionObjects.Add(SO);